# With tkinter, how to add or remove Entries or Labels via optionmenu selection?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using tkinter. When a person using my program selects from a dropdown menu (created with `OptionMenu`), depending on what the selection is, I want `Entry` fields to appear. So if they select `a` from the menu, an `Entry` field should appear so they can enter a number like `11.6`.

Then if the user selects `b` from the option menu, I want 2 `Entry` fields to appear.

I have been trying to do this with the `OptionMenu`'s `command=function` parameter, but I think its not working because I am trying to create and edit Entries within the function that is launched.

Btw, the code should still work if the user switches between selecting 'a' and 'b' - this is what I'm having trouble with.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
rc = 0

types = ['a', 'b', 'c']

type_header = Label(root, text='Select Type:', font='-weight bold')
type_header.grid(row=rc, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky=W)
rc += 1

tvar0 = StringVar(root)
tvar1 = StringVar(root)
tvar2 = StringVar(root)

type_label_0 = Label(root, text='row1:')
type_label_0.grid(row=rc, column=0, sticky=E)
type_list = OptionMenu(root, tvar0, *types, command=optc)  
type_list.config(width=15)
type_list.grid(row=rc, column=1, sticky=W)
rc += 1

type_label_1 = Label(root, text='row2:')
type_label_1.grid(row=rc, column=0, sticky=E)
type_list = OptionMenu(root, tvar1, *types, command=optc)  
type_list.config(width=15)
type_list.grid(row=rc, column=1, sticky=W)
rc += 1

def optc(v):

    if v == 'a':
        # if option 'a' selected, just have one label, and one entry box

        t0_label1 = Label(root, text='  temperature:')
        t0_label1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

        t0_field1 = Entry(root)
        t0_field1.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
        t0_field1.config(width=7)

    if v == 'b':
        # if option 'b', then 2 labels and 2 entry boxes
        t0_label1 = Label(root, text='  height:')
        t0_label1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

        t0_field1 = Entry(root)
        t0_field1.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
        t0_field1.config(width=7)

        t0_label2 = Label(root, text='  width:')
        t0_label2.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)

        t0_field2 = Entry(root)
        t0_field2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
        t0_field2.config(width=7)
```

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: Define a function before calling it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a later version of code when I was trying to debug. Normally optc was defined before it was called.

Answer (score -1):

> I think its not working because I am trying to create and edit Entries
>   within the function that is launched.

What makes you think the function is launched?  Your code gives a

```
NameError: name 'optc' is not defined
```

when you try to create the first OptionMenu.  Python gives pretty good error messages. This one is telling you that opc has to be defined *before* it can be assigned to the OptionMenu.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable answer if you explain how to fix the error. Shame the down voter didn't explain their reason for clicking the down arrow.

Comment: Sorry, that was a later version of code when I was trying to debug. Normally optc was defined before it was called.